# How can I arrange these adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-order

Is this sentence correct? (I need it as a title).

> *Muscular enhancement exercising aiding method.*

I am not sure if one of the following sentences is the correct:

> Aiding muscle exercising enhancement method.
>
> Muscle aiding  exercising enhancement method.
>
> Muscle exercising enhancement aiding method.

What is the rule governing the order of adjectives like these ones?

Thanks all

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to say in the first place. Is it a *muscle exercising* method, or a *muscle enhancing* method, or what? At any rate, most of these words seem redundant. (–1 for not hiring someone to do your advertising work)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback anyway, I mean enhancement by exercising.

Comment: They aren't adjectives, but attributive nouns, and unless we know exactly what you're trying to say it's impossible to say which (if any) of your paraphrases is correct. What is enhanced, by whom or what? What is aided, by whom or what? Does *exercising* mean that somebody (who?) or something (what?) performs exercises, or does that somebody/thing exercise something else (what?)?

Comment: As a title, simplify it by dropping *aiding method* altogether and focus on the exercise itself. I would use something like *(The / A / Our) Muscular Enhancement Exercise*. Or, if there are actually several exercises, *Muscular Enhancement Exercises*. (If it's more about the method, then use that word rather than *exercise*. All of those things together is wrong.)

Comment: By the way, none of those is a *sentence*, because they don't have a subject and a conjugated verb.  They are phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Muscle enhancement exercises*

would suffice. The phrase **aiding method** is redundant when you already have "Muscle enhancement exercise", unless this ancillary method is something over and above the exercise itself, such as anaerobic conditioning.

And the word **enhancement** doesn't seem quite idiomatic. Is this in a rehabilitation context where a debilitated muscle is brought back to health, or a form of strength-training, to make a normal muscle a super muscle?

In any case, stringing those words together like that is usually a sign that the speaker is unaware of a more idiomatic way of expressing the idea, so to ask for the rule that governs their order is like asking for the proper way to do something improperly.